# zimbra doesnt receive mail from php mail function

Tags: php, email, zimbra

- I am using normal code to send mail in PHP.
- Its having no problem of sending to gmail, yahoo, Hotmail,etc..
- but in zimbra it doesn't receive..

Answer (score 0):

Check logs on Zimbra MTA server, it's located at:

```
/var/log/maillog
```

Check if you see you php-server trying to reach Zimbra. You may get blocked cause Zimbra think you php-server is sending spam, or fail on one of many checks. Either way, the maillog should say something about it.